The concentration Inequality about covariance matrix
When I read a note about concentration inequality, I came across a question about how the author proved it. When we sample from a Gaussian distribution with zero mean but different covariance matrices, we get samples $X_1^1, X_2^1,\dots, X_{n_1}^1 \sim \mathcal{N}\left(0,\Sigma_1\right), X_1^2, X_2^2,\dots, X_{n_2}^2 \sim \mathcal{N}\left(0,\Sigma_2\right),\dots, X_1^{|\mathcal{A}|}, X_2^{|\mathcal{A}|},\dots, X_{n_{|\mathcal{A}|}}^{|\mathcal{A}|} \sim \mathcal{N}\left(0,\Sigma_{|\mathcal{A}|}\right)$ and we get estimators
$$
\hat{S}=\frac{1}{n_{\mathcal{A}}}\sum_{k\in\mathcal{A}}\sum_{i=1,\dots,n_{k}} x_{i}^{k}\left(x_{i}^{k}\right)^{\top}, \hat{S_{k}}=\frac{1}{n_{\mathcal{k}}}\sum_{i=1,\dots,n_{k}} x_{i}^{k}\left(x_{i}^{k}\right)^{\top}
$$
The problem I am concerned about is the concentrated inequality of $\hat{S}$. The author writes
$$
\mathbb{P}\left(\|\hat{S}-\sum_{k\in\mathcal{A}}\left(\frac{n_k}{n_{\mathcal{A}}}\Sigma_{k}\right)\|_{\max}\ge t\right)\le \mathbb{P}\left(\sum_{k\in\mathcal{A}}\frac{n_k}{n_{\mathcal{A}}}\left(\hat{S}_k-\Sigma_k\right)\ge t\right)\le\sum_{k\in\mathcal{A}}\mathbb{P}\left(\|\hat{S}_k-\Sigma_k\|_\max\ge \frac{tn_{\mathcal{A}}}{|\mathcal{A}|n_k}\right)\\ \le p^2\sum_{k\in \mathcal{A}}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2\pi^2}\frac{t^2n_{\mathcal{A}}^2}{|\mathcal{A}|^2n_k}\right)
\le p^2\exp\left(-cn_{\mathcal{A}}t^2\right)
$$
where $\mathcal{A}$ is a set and $n_{\mathcal{A}}=n_1+n_2+\cdots+n_{|\mathcal{A}|}$ and $|\mathcal{A}|$ represents the number of elements in set $\mathcal{A}$. $\|\dot\|_{\max}$ denotes the maximum absolute value of the element in the matrix.
Now I don't know how to get the last inequality and there is no more information about $c$. I guess $c$ is a large enough constant and does not depend on $|\mathcal{A}|$.
UPDATE:
we have
$$
\mathbb{P}\left(\|\hat{S}_k-\Sigma_k\|_{\max}\ge t\right) \le p^2\exp\left(-\frac{n_kt^2}{2\pi^2}\right).
$$

The inequality can not hold for all t. Indeed for $t = 0$, the LHS is $p^2 |A|$ and the RHS is $p^2$.

@jvc Thanks a lot and I made a mistake.
